# Image of an isotropic manifold under lagrangian correspondence is isotropic?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, lagrangian-submanifolds, isotropic-submanifolds

Is the following statement well known?

Let $M,N$ be symplectic (algebraic) manifolds. Let $L \subset M \times N$ be a (smooth)
[Lagrangian correspondence](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lagrangian+correspondence). For a subset $X \subset M$ we denote $L(X):=(y\in N|(x,y)\in L)$.
Let $X \subset M$ be an isotropic subvariety (i.e. its smooth locus is isotropic). Then $L(X)$ is isotropic.

Is it written somewhere? I think I can prove it and it is quite simple, but I'll rather use a reference instead.

Thank you

Comment: You should clarify your definition of $L(X)$. ie. does it consist of those $y\in N$ for which $X\times \{y\} \subset L$ or just those $y$ for which there exists an $x\in X$ such that $(x,y) \in L$ ? And does ''correspondence'' just mean $L$ is a subset of $M \times N$ or something more?

Comment: Plus, i think good advice might be to just forego looking for any reference and providing the one line proof which it requires. 

Comment: to  J. Martel.  Is it better now? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We have written the proof in Appendix B.1. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3630.pdf.